# Let $N \unlhd G$ and let $N \leqslant H \leqslant G$. Show that $N \unlhd H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $N \unlhd G$ and let $N \leqslant H \leqslant G$. Show that $N \unlhd H$.

$N \unlhd G$  implies that there is some homomorphism $f$ on $G$ for which $N = ker(f)$. We want to show that there is a homormorphism $f'$ on H such that $N = ker(f')$.

Edit:

Proof. The function $f: G \to G/N$ is a surjective group homorphism with $ker(f) = N$. For $a,b \in G$, we have $f(ab) = abN$ and $f(a)f(b) = (aN)(bN) = abN$, demonstrating that $f$ is a homomorphism. For $a \in G$, we have $$a \in ker(f) \Longleftrightarrow aN = N \Longleftrightarrow a \in N.$$ This shows $ker(f) = N$. Finally, $f$ is surjective, since every left coset is of the form $aN = f(a)$ for some $a \in G$. Since $H \leqslant G$, we can define a map $f':H \hookrightarrow G \to G/N$, $h \mapsto aN$ for $h \in H \leqslant G$. It follows that $f'$ is also a surjective homomorphism and that $ker(f') = N$. Thus $N \unlhd H$. $\text{ } \Box$

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $H \hookrightarrow G \to G/N$

---

Edit: (Concerning your edit)

Your proof looks good, just a few things to mention:

- you don't need surjectivity of any map (it is given but not necessary). Also if a map $G \to M$ is not surjective, it will factor through a surjective map, since the image $M'$ of the map is a subgroup. Hence we have $G\to M' \to M$
- probably a typo, but the map $f':H \hookrightarrow G \to G/N$ is $h \mapsto hN$
- hence $f'$ is not necessarily surjective! (but as mentioned above we don't need that)
- if you already go into detail you could mention why $ker(f')=N$ (which is easy)

As a last comment, let me mention that the properties of the quotient map are usually assumed as given, because they are very basic. But if you use this the first time it is good to prove everything.

Comment: What does "$\hookrightarrow$" stand for? Is it a special type of map?

Comment: inclusion or embedding. In general it just indicates "injective", but if you have a natural identification with a subgroup for example, it indicates that this is the inclusion.

Comment: Is the map $G \to G/N$ the "natural epimorphism"? https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Natural_Epimorphism/Group

Comment: yes. it is called the quotient map.

Comment: you wrote above that $N$ is the kernel of some $f$. You can basically just precompose this map with the inclusion and the above composition becomes the form: $H \to G \stackrel f \to H$.

Comment: I sketched a proof. Please let me know if there are any errors in it. Thank you.

Comment: I added a detailed comment on your proof.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  $N$ is normal in $G$ because conjugating it by any element of $G$ leaves it invariant. Elements of $H$ are elements of $G$.

Comment: I edited my question. Some feedback would be appreciated.